# Shipping an app with Strip Debug Symbols On/Off

Tags: ios, xcode, security, debugging, debug-symbols

It seems that the size of the binary can get bloated when `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` is set to NO. And also why would you want to ship debug symbols with your app? When I create a new project in Xcode, it gets this option set to NO, for both Debug and Release, even if the "iOS Default" is supposed to be YES (as seen in the "Levels" settings view mode). Why would I not want to strip debug symbols when keeping them could potentially make it easier to reverse engineer my apps? Isn't it always an option for crash reports to depend on dSYM files? Or no dSYM files can be generated when this option is YES?

Should I have `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` YES or NO for my apps? How do I best provide crash reports with the necessary info when `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` is YES?

Comment: By doing reverse engineering work for OSX/iOS for many years and for many reasons, all I can say is even if you turned that on, there will most likely still be enough symbols left for reverse engineering/understanding what your app was doing, as long as you wrote your iOS/OSX app with Objective-C/Swift. As for crackers, there won't be much difference if he/she is a "*pro*". If he/she decided to went through all the troubles, dump out clean binary of your app, load it into tools like IDA Pro, there won't be much you can do to under Apple's current guideline ("no-packer-allowed" policy).

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai Interesting info, thank you. The question still remains of whether crash reports need all that sizable amount of data that increases the app's size or there are more size-efficient ways?

Comment: Proper Crash Reporter System don't need any symbols in your app binary, all they need is the separate (more detailed) dSYM.

Comment: @Kerni So it makes no sense to keep debug symbols because dSYM is independent?